# My elements are not going on the same line - using "display:inline"

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at the code and tell me what I'm doing wrong? I want "Hi" to go to the right of the table. I've tried putting "float:left" on all elements and on each individually.

```
<div style="display:inline">

<h1>Heading</h1>

<ul>
<li><h4>Reason 1</h4></li>
<li><h4>Reason 2</h4></li>
<li><h4>Reason 3</h4></li>
<li><h4>Reason 4</h4></li>
<li><h4>Reason 5</h4></li>
</ul>

<h1>Hi</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: and what is your css?

Answer (score 1):

display property will not be inherited by all child elements. you have to specify it for `li` specifically, or else default display of `list-item` will be used for `li`

```
<div>

<h1>Heading</h1>

<ul>
<li style="display:inline"><h4>Reason 1</h4></li>
<li style="display:inline"><h4>Reason 2</h4></li>
<li style="display:inline"><h4>Reason 3</h4></li>
<li style="display:inline"><h4>Reason 4</h4></li>
<li style="display:inline"><h4>Reason 5</h4></li>
</ul>

<h1>Hi</h1>
</div>
```

and to remove the mess we do CSS

```
<style>
#inline-list li{
    display: inline-block;//or inline as you like
}
</style>
<div>

<h1>Heading</h1>

<ul id="inline-list">
<li><h4>Reason 1</h4></li>
<li><h4>Reason 2</h4></li>
<li><h4>Reason 3</h4></li>
<li><h4>Reason 4</h4></li>
<li><h4>Reason 5</h4></li>
</ul>

<h1>Hi</h1>
</div>
```

Or do you want something like this? Heading, list and other heading in same line?

```
<div>

<h1 style="float:left">Heading</h1>

<ul style="float:left">
<li><h4>Reason 1</h4></li>
<li><h4>Reason 2</h4></li>
<li><h4>Reason 3</h4></li>
<li><h4>Reason 4</h4></li>
<li><h4>Reason 5</h4></li>
</ul>

<h1 style="float:left">Hi</h1>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nXC8Z/

Comment: default value of the property `display` is `list-item`, not `block`. Just set block and see the bullets disappear ;)

Comment: @FelipeAls thankyou for correcting I was just thinking about the layout.

Answer (score 0):

ur using inline on on div and that is not applying on inner items

so try this

```
<style>div * {display:inline;}</style>
```

or make each item inline separately in css

as i understand from ur question u want

```
<div>

<h1 style="float:left;">Heading</h1>

<ul style="float:left;">
<li style="display:inline"><h4>Reason 1</h4></li>
<li style="display:inline"><h4>Reason 2</h4></li>
<li style="display:inline"><h4>Reason 3</h4></li>
<li style="display:inline"><h4>Reason 4</h4></li>
<li style="display:inline"><h4>Reason 5</h4></li>
</ul>

<h1 style="float:right;">Hi</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `h1`, `ul` and `h1` to display in one row (room permitting), you'll want `inline-block`:

```
<style>
.inlines {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<div>

<h1 class="inlines">Heading</h1>

<ul class="inlines">
  <li><h4>Reason 1</h4></li>
  <li><h4>Reason 2</h4></li>
  <li><h4>Reason 3</h4></li>
  <li><h4>Reason 4</h4></li>
  <li><h4>Reason 5</h4></li>
</ul>

<h1 class="inlines">Hi</h1>
</div>
```

If you want the individual list items in the same single row, add:

```
.inlines li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

For an example, see this CodePen: http://cdpn.io/GLhqK